# Array with arithmetic operator?

Tags: c, arrays

I have been reviewing some existing code and am hung up on a line. I put all of the code that should be relevant to the question down below. Note, the variable `evt` is a part of an enumeration type that contains 36 elements, I however only wrote 3 of the 36 for simplicity.

The line in question is:

```
events[evt / 32] |= (uint32_t)1 << (evt % 32);
```

I cant seem to wrap my head around how or why one would place `evt / 32` in the array index call out. It seems to me that all but 4 product elements from the 36 value enumeration would be truncated. Please excuse my poor terminology as I am still a learning C. If anyone could help me understand what is going on here I would very much appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

```
static volatile uint32_t events[8];

typdef enum event_e
{
EVT_1,
EVT_2,
EVT_36
}event_t;

void event_set(event_t evt)
{
events[evt / 32] |= (uint32_t)1 << (evt % 32);
}
```

Comment: Try some examples.  When `evt == 5` this will set bit `5` of `events[0]`.  When `evt == 34` it will set bit 2 of `events[1]`.

Comment: `evt` is a number in nature so you can do arithmetic operations on it. by dividing it to 32 you get an integer between 0 and 1 and these are correct index for `events`.

Comment: I notice that `events` is volatile and likely accessed by multiple threads concurrently. It's worth noting that the `|=` operation is non atomic and can give unexpected results if multiple threads try to set events at the same time. There's a chance that one of the event sets will be overwritten and missed.

Answer (score 6):

`events` is a bit map, and this is setting the bit that corresponds to the value of `evt` to `1`. The first 32 bits go into `events[0]`, the next 4 bits go into `events[1]`. `evt % 32` gets the remainder, which is the bit offset, and `1 << (evt % 32)` shifts `1` to that offset.